# Functional testing for Mac App

Tags: cocoa, macos, cucumber, functional-testing

Is there any functional testing framework for Mac apps, similar to Cucumber framework?

Comment: Good question. There are quite a few choices for iOS now but it seems strange there aren't any for native apps. I would think porting over something like Frank wouldn't be too difficult since OS X and iOS have very similar APIs.

Answer (score 1):

[Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) is perfectly usable for Mac OS X application functional testing.

Comment: This was not true when the question was originally answered, but Frank recently introduced Mac support. http://www.buckleyisms.com/home/2013/7/31/announcing-frank-for-mac.html